# How to initialize a dictionary with keys as items from inner list?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm stuck at dictionary initialization, where I need to get a dictionary, where keys are item inner list elements, and the values are these items. It's very hard for me to explain, so here is an example.
There is a structure

```cs
public class Process
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and some data:

```
Process 1
   Product 1
   Product 2

Process 2
   Product 2
   Product 3
```

In the end a dictionary should looks like this:

```cs
Dictionary<Product, List<Process>>()
{
    { Product1, List<Process> { Process1 },
    { Product2, List<Process> { Process1, Process2 },
    { Product3, List<Process> { Process2 } }
}
```

So, somehow I need to get unique keys (Product.Id) from every Process, and set values as processes, where each product contains.

I tried some linq `Select`'s for Product collection, but it create an Enumerable, so i cant use it as key. And I dont find any questions that described the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *efficient* solution could be iterating the *processes* list just once and creating the desired dictionary.

```
var processList = new List<Process>();

var result = new Dictionary<Product, List<Process>>();
var product1 = new Product() { Id = 1 };
var product2 = new Product() { Id = 2 };
var product3 = new Product() { Id = 3 };
processList.Add(new Process() { Products = new List<Product>() { product1, product2 } });
processList.Add(new Process() { Products = new List<Product>() { product2, product3 } });

foreach(var process in processList)
{
   foreach(var product in process.Products)
   {
       if (!result.ContainsKey(product))
          result.Add(product, new List<Process>());
       result[product].Add(process);
   }
}
```

Output

```
{ Product1, List<Process> { Process1 },
{ Product2, List<Process> { Process1, Process2 },
{ Product3, List<Process> { Process2 } }
```

Comment: thank you for solution! Works well.   
Generally, I just looking for some linq-based code, but my initial thoughts about this problem was wrong. 
I get this error when getting some data from db with entity framework 6, and dont set up ef properly so i always get Quaryable, and when I iterate through it, ef makes thousands of select and execute it, so i think it would be better to get all the data to RAM and work with it.